# Number of Island leetcode python

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, multidimensional-array, depth-first-search

The question reads as the following:  Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        # use dfs / replace the island's elements with a sign "."
        a = len(grid)
        b = len(grid[0])
        num = 0


        for i in range(0 , a-1):
            for j in range(0 , b-1):
                if grid[i][j] == '1':
                    num += 1
                    self.dfs(grid , i , j)

        return num

    def dfs(self, grid , x , y):

        if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= len(grid[0]) or y >= len(grid) or grid[x][y] == '0' or grid[x][y] == ".": # if out of boundary
            return

        grid[x][y] = "."        
        # if 1's has only one neighbor

        self.dfs(grid , x-1 , y)   # check 4 edges of water
        self.dfs(grid, x+1 , y)
        self.dfs(grid , x , y+1)
        self.dfs(grid , x , y- 1)
```

This code only works for this output: [["1","1","1","1","0"],["1","1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0","0"]]

However, it does not work for this output: [["1","1","0","0","0"],["1","1","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","0","0"],["0","0","0","1","1"]]

I am trying to use the dfs method. Thus, if x is in the array, function dfs would check the neighbor elements from 4 sides whether it is "1" or not, if it is "1", then it is replaced by ".". otherwise, if the element is "0", the recursive loop stops. Once all recursive loop stops for every possible combinations, The count is incremented by 1. Then the program runs to find other "X".

However, the program does not work properly. Therefore, Could anyone helps me to find problems in this code?

Comment: `range`'s end is excluded from the range, so try replacing `a-1` and `b-1` with just `a` and `b`

Comment: I tried that but the list index is out of range only for second output

Comment: looks like this condition should be the other way around: `x >= len(grid[0]) or y >= len(grid)` (you use `x` as "rows" and `y` as "cols")

Comment: I also tried that but it said b = len(grid[0]) is out of index range somehow

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately, can not find what is wrong with your code, I did one myself it is a little different but it works, perhaps it can help find the issue in yours

```
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        
        def is_land(grid, next_loc):
            
            (x, y) = next_loc
            
            grid[x][y] = '0'
            
            if x+1 < rows and grid[x+1][y] == '1':
                grid = is_land(grid, (x+1, y))
            
            if x - 1 >= 0 and grid[x-1][y] == '1':
                grid = is_land(grid, (x-1, y))
            
            if y+1 < cols and grid[x][y+1] == '1':
                grid = is_land(grid, (x, y+1))
            
            if y-1 >= 0 and grid[x][y-1] == '1':
                grid = is_land(grid, (x, y-1))
            
            return grid
        
        rows = len(grid)
        cols = len(grid[0])
        ans = 0
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                if grid[row][col] == '1':
                    grid = is_land(grid, (row, col))
                    ans += 1
        return ans
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend decoupling the approach more so its easier to identify the issue and adjust. When solving graph problems in general, it's best to approach as such.

1. Build the graph
2. Implement traversal algorithm
3. Are multiple launches required for traversal algorithm?

   ```
   class Solution(object):
       def numIslands(self, grid):
           # build graph
           # traverse 
           # function handling

           if grid is None:
               return 0

           islands = 0 

           def getneighbors(x,y):
               result = []
               if x+1 < len(grid):
                   result.append((x+1, y))
               if y+1 < len(grid[0]):
                   result.append((x, y+1))
               if x-1 >= 0:
                   result.append((x-1, y))
               if y-1 >= 0:
                   result.append((x, y-1))
               return result        

           def dfs(i, j):            
               grid[i][j] = "0"
               neighbors = getneighbors(i,j)
               for (nr,nc) in neighbors:
                   if grid[nr][nc] != "0":
                       dfs(nr, nc)

           for i in range(len(grid)):
               for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                   if grid[i][j] != "0":
                       islands += 1
                       dfs(i, j)
           return islands
   ```

Note: Make sure grid[i][j] = "0" when visited first and not capture otherwise queue size will be large causing time limit exceeding errors